# ResolvePrincipal vs SearchPrincipal

Tags: 2013, user-profile, people-picker

So I'm attempting to write something to mimic sharepoint's people picker. I was originally using `Utility.ResolvePrincipal` with some success, but it was only returning me a single user (obviously). So, I tried to use `Utility.SearchPrincipal`. Only that's not returning me anything. Here's what I have:

```
var user = Utility.ResolvePrincipal(_clientContext, _clientContext.Web, nameStart, PrincipalType.user, PrincipalSource.All, null, false);
var users = Utility.SearchPrincipals(_clientContext, _clientContext.Web, nameStart, PrincipalType.user, PrincipalSource.All, null, 10);
_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

At this point, user.Value has a single user, and users is an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try below correction in your code :

var users = Utility.SearchPrincipals(_clientContext, _clientCOntext.Web, nameStart, PrincipalType.user, **PrincipalSource.All**, null, 10);
_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: Good catch, but it was just a transcription error.

Comment: Grab a copy of iLspy and take a look how it works internally in SharePoint you can pretty much use identical code. This is always my first go to when I don't know how to do something but it already exists in SharePoint. You can consider to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.search.aspx if you want more profile information as well.

Comment: `UserProfileManager` looks like it only works with an `SPServiceContext` and not a `ClientContext`.

Comment: I looked through the source with ILSpy, but there wasn't anything useful in there. The code is nearly identical for `ResolvePrincipal` and `SearchPrincipals`.

Comment: I'm thinking you are running into an issue when peeking into all of those PrincipalSource.All sources. Perhaps a permissions issue? Are you really able to get into a RoleProvider, MembershipProvider, Active Directory and the UIL between the client and the 2013 Provider Host? ResolvePrincipal(...) stops looking when it finds a single user. The first enum in PrincipalSource is the UIL. But, SearchPrincipals(...) has to go through all of its other possible sources (when using .All) and may be unhappy with the walls it's hitting. - Good luck (:

Comment: SPServiceContext is the new Office.Server.ServiceContext for SharePoint. However you can use using (new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContextScope(SPServiceContext.GetContext(site))) if you have a null HttpContext/SPContext to open a service context.

Comment: @Wartickler: That was it! I switched the PrincipalSource to UIL, and I got 2 results! (Both different than ResolveUser got, and they're both SecurityGruoups for some reason, but hey! Results!)

Comment: Also, @Wartickler, if you answer the question with that, I'll accept it and give you the bounty.

Comment: Glad I could help, Colin (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking you are running into an issue when peeking into all of those `PrincipalSource.All` sources. Perhaps a permissions issue?

Are you really able to get into a RoleProvider, MembershipProvider, Active Directory and the UIL between the client and the 2013 Provider Host? `ResolvePrincipal(...)` stops looking when it finds a single user. The first enum in PrincipalSource is the UIL. But, `SearchPrincipals(...)` has to go through all of its other possible sources (when using .All) and may be unhappy with the walls it's hitting.

Good luck (:

Answer (score 2):

My example from project, correctly works with users and groups.

```
    public Principal ResolvePrincipal(string name)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new ArgumentException("Principal name is empty");

        Principal result = null;

        var info = Utility.ResolvePrincipal(Context, Context.Web, name, PrincipalType.All, PrincipalSource.All, null, false);
        Context.ExecuteQuery();

        if (info.Value.PrincipalType == PrincipalType.User)
            result = Context.Web.EnsureUser(info.Value.LoginName);

        if (info.Value.PrincipalType == PrincipalType.SharePointGroup || info.Value.PrincipalType == PrincipalType.SecurityGroup)
            result = Context.Web.SiteGroups.GetById(info.Value.PrincipalId);

        Context.Load(result);
        Context.ExecuteQuery();

        return result;
    }
```

And tests

```
rep.ResolvePrincipal("i:0#.f|membership|admin@helpdesk02.onmicrosoft.com");  //return user
rep.ResolvePrincipal("admin@helpdesk02.onmicrosoft.com"); //return user
rep.ResolvePrincipal("Help Desk Owners"); // return group Help Desk Owners
rep.ResolvePrincipal("1"); //return User with Id = 1
rep.ResolvePrincipal("Roman Rylov"); //return User
rep.ResolvePrincipal(""); //throw Exception
```

Comment: This doesn't really apply to my question at all (which I have resolved, and which has an accepted answer). My question was around how to get a full list of users for searching. Your code does look useful, just not for this.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same a couple of weeks ago. In my case i used [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SearchPrincipals) to search for persons and it worked quite well. In my case i used the web service to search persons.

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "SearchPrincipals",
  webURL: "/",
  searchText: "bauer",
  maxResults: 100,
  SPPrincipalType: "SPPrincipalType.User",
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    alert(xData);
  }
});
```

Do you get any error back?

Comment: That's giving me a 401 unauthorized because this is a SharePoint 2013 Provider Hosted app that lives inside a different domain than the actual SharePoint site.

Answer (score 1):

> Retrieve a Sharepoint principal by Active Directory user or group name
>
> Now this one took me a very long time. For some reason there is a
>   static Utility.SearchPrincipals method that gets you a PrincipalInfo
>   object, but you can never get to get a Principal object that you can
>   use for setting permissions. I spent a long time scratching my head
>   how to get around this before I found there is another way:

```
public Principal GetPrincipal(string name)
{
  if (web != null)
  {
    try
    {
      var principal = web.EnsureUser(name);
      clientContext.Load(principal);
      clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
      if (principal != null)
      {
        return principal;
      }
    }
    catch (ServerException){}
  }
  return null;
}
```

using the method like so:

```
var g = sh.GetPrincipal("MyUserGroup");
var u = sh.GetPrincipal("MyUser");
```

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/sharepoint-client-object-model-sites.html

Comment: This doesn't really help. I already know how to get the actual principal after I get the Principal Info through (well, hopefully SearchPrincipals) but right now through ResolvePrincipal.

Comment: Solved my problem! I actually start banging my head into Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles, now I can stop! Thanks!

Comment: so the insight here is that `EnsureUser()` actually works for groups too?