# Get Principal By Id - Getting User or Group by ID

Tags: permissions, csom, user-information-list

How to get a CSOM `Principal` from a user or group ID?

For example to assign permissions stored in a "People" field (which can also contain groups).

At the moment I have this super kludge using `ExceptionHandlingScope`.

```
void AddRole(SecurableObject securable, int principalId, RoleDefinition role)
{
    var scope = new ExceptionHandlingScope(context);
    using (scope.StartScope())
    {
        using (scope.StartTry())
        {
            var principal = context.Web.SiteUsers.GetById(principalId);
            securable.RoleAssignments.Add(principal, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context) { role });
        }
        using (scope.StartCatch())
        {
            var principal = context.Web.SiteGroups.GetById(principalId);
            securable.RoleAssignments.Add(principal, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context) { role });
        }
    }
}
```

The REST API just accepts raw principal ID, but that loses a lot of the advantages of using the CSOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ResolvePrincipal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee540627(v%3Doffice.15)) method in the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities` namespace.

It accepts the principal ID, but you need to send it as `string` instead of `int`. Also, instead of ID, if you directly want to send the user's or group's name, it would work

It would work as below:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;    
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities;

void AddRole(SecurableObject securable, int principalId, RoleDefinition role)
{       
    var info = Utility.ResolvePrincipal(context, context.Web, principalId.ToString(), PrincipalType.All, PrincipalSource.All, null, false);

    context.ExecuteQuery();

    Principal principal = null;

    if (info.Value.PrincipalType == PrincipalType.User)
    {
        principal = context.Web.SiteUsers.GetById(principalId);
    }
    else if (info.Value.PrincipalType == PrincipalType.SharePointGroup
          || info.Value.PrincipalType == PrincipalType.SecurityGroup)
    {
        principal = Context.Web.SiteGroups.GetById(info.Value.PrincipalId);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException($"PrincipalType {info.Value.PrincipalType}");
    }

    securable.RoleAssignments.Add(result, new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context) { role });
}
```

Modified from here - [ResolvePrincipal vs SearchPrincipal](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/93629/8068)

Comment: that's interesting to know, but unfortunately requires an additional `ExecuteQuery` call.

Comment: ps. I briefly tried this code and for some reason it returned a completely different principal. eg. resolve "10" and returns principal id "135".  Haven't had a chance to troubleshoot.